# Careers 2.0 - Add project button does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When attempting to add one of the projects I've worked on ('http://galos.no-ip.org/x86gameboy') I enter the URL into the field, but upon clicking the 'Add Project' button , nothing happens, and the following exception appears in the Javascript inspector:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <p><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="q" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></p>


<p>         
    We found the following project.

</p>    
<form action="/cv/updateproject/124779?id=0" class="no-ajax" method="post">      <label>
<img alt="" class="favicon" src="http://galos.no-ip.org/favicon.ico">            Project  name
</label>

<input id="CustomName" name="CustomName" type="text" value="x86gameboy" />        <label>Project description</label>
<textarea cols="20" id="CustomDescription" name="CustomDescription" rows="2">
</textarea>        <label>Technologies</label>
<input id="CustomTags" name="CustomTags" type="text" value="" />        <label>Your Role/Contribution</label>
<textarea cols="20" id="Notes" name="Notes" rows="2">
</textarea>        <br class="clear" />
<input id="Url" name="Url" type="hidden" value="http://galos.no-ip.org/x86gameboy" /><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Provider field is required." id="Provider" name="Provider" type="hidden" value="Other" /><input id="FaviconUrl" name="FaviconUrl" type="hidden" value="http://galos.no-ip.org/favicon.ico" /><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsOpenSource field is required." id="IsOpenSource" name="IsOpenSource" type="hidden" value="False" /><input data-saved-text="added project" data-saving-text="adding project" id="save" name="save" type="submit" value="add project" /><a class="cancel" href="/cv/edit/124779#apps" title="discard changes">cancel</a><input id="fkey" name="fkey" type="hidden" value="80cdca10ca66ee91deb21b8159890dfc" /></form>
```

With the following traceback:

```
jquery.min.js:4
st.error jquery.min.js:4
ft jquery.min.js:4
wt jquery.min.js:4
st jquery.min.js:4
b.fn.extend.find jquery.min.js:4
b.fn.b.init jquery.min.js:3
b jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous function) careerscdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/import.min.js?v=75faa7cc99a5:1
c jquery.min.js:3
p.fireWith jquery.min.js:3
k jquery.min.js:5
r jquery.min.js:5
```

The project has no online scm; so although this seems like a bug, could there something I'm failing to do on my end?

EDIT: 
It looks like this may be coming from a 404 on some requested javascript:

```
GET http://careerscdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/jquery.migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate-prod.min.js 404 (Not Found) 124779:231
```

Comment: The problem seems to have been resolved